# How to know when is the github action will be started?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am currently using the GitHub actions feature for my project CI-CD, so the pipeline listens to push on the main branch, and when I do no action gets triggered on the actions tab, also I try to run that pipeline manually since I have `workflow_dispatch`  and it says

```
Workflow run was successfully requested.
```

I don't understand is there a queuing system for actions or are there some priorities? and also I would like to know when and whether the action is going to start?

## Update:

The github action started after few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must depend on the Azure server load and availability.

For instance, [scheduled actions](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.3/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) come with the caveat:

> Note: The schedule event can be delayed during periods of high loads of GitHub Actions workflow runs.
> High load times include the start of every hour.
> To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.

In your case, you were scheduling the job manually, but it had to wait for other jobs to complete first.

Plus, in your case, there was a [GitHub Actions incident report](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/vvthhf8gxt80) earlier today, which could have has a side-effect regarding the scheduling your your job.