# Ignore Dependabot notifications for 3rd party Repositories

Tags: github, dependabot

Is it possible to watch a 3rd party repository on Github, but ignore any notification generated by dependabot?

For example, I want to follow development in a repository like:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation

But dependabot is generating too much noise:

[image]

*NOTE:* There is a similar question for **your own** repositories, but I'm specifically curious about monitoring **3rd party** repositories: [How to disable or ignore Dependabot pull requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72507630/how-to-disable-or-ignore-dependabot-pull-requests)

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169159/on-github-how-to-ignore-all-dependabot-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to filter out Dependabot "bump" merge commits when monitoring the notification of a third party project.

But what you can do is dedicate your own repository in which you can set up your own GitHub Action, on [a schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003326/6309).
It would, once a day (or more often):

- [check out the third-party (public) repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889190/6309)
- check the logs for any new (non-bump) commit on `main`or `master`.
- send an email if any are detected
- store the last detected commit in a file ([`actions/update-files-on-github`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-files-on-github)), in order to facilitate the next check for new commits.

Comment: This sounds like a clever solution - but also, a decent amount of work; is this basically building my own notification system into GitHub?

Comment: @PhilipPittle For that particular use case, yes, you would build your own notification system, but using GitHub infrastructure.

Comment: @PhilipPittle I see this was downvoted, and was hoping for another answer with a better solution. I would still recommend for you to test the dedicated scheduled GitHub Action approach.

Comment: ya, I was hoping there was a way to use the built-in GitHub notification system, but sounds like it's just not possible.  Thanks for this!